# "The primary reason why" vs "The primary reason that"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which of the above is correct?

> "The primary reason why something happens is...."

vs

> "The primary reason that something happens is...."

Could I say both of these sentences?

Comment: **The reason that...** is correct although **the reason why..** is often heard, especially in: **I don't know the reason why it happened**.