# "One of the reasons why ..." vs "One of the reasons (no why) ..."

Tags: ellipsis, writing

Will the words "One of the reasons why I ..." be considered wordy? Should I just write "One of the reasons I ..." or there is no much difference between them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['reason' vs 'reason that'.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55458/reason-vs-reason-that) Also ["The primary reason why" vs "The primary reason that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267120/the-primary-reason-why-vs-the-primary-reason-that) and several others closed in favour of that first link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes that one answered my question but KateBunting(below) provided an interesting article too.

Answer (score 0):

Including "why" is very common in both written and spoken English, as you can verify by searching any large database of English texts. (Google gave me about 13.7 million results for "one of the reasons why I" as an exact phrase.) English speakers do usually try to avoid wordiness, but a single three-letter word is unlikely to be seen as excessive. Unless you have special considerations (for example, if you're writing a newspaper headline or poetry), there is very little difference between your two options.

Comment: While planning to answer this question I found [this article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-there-a-reason-the-reason-why-is-considered-wrong/).

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting! I'm somewhat surprised that he didn't address "the reason for which". (He also mentions “the place where”, which is analogous to "the place at which", etc.) I chose to keep my answer short rather than delve deeply into the issue, but a lot can definitely be said about it.